# ¿Cómo usar el old de un select Laravel?

Tags: laravel, select

En la función `edit` de mi controlador, deseo pasarme el valor que ya tengo seleccionado en país, es un `select` y no sé cómo aplicar el `old`.

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $empresa = Empresa::findOrFail($id);
    $paises = Pais::where('activo', 1)->pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray();
    $page = $request->query('page');

    return view('admin.vbk_emp_ing01.edit', [

        'paises'           => $paises,
        'model'            => $empresa,
        'cancel_link'      => route('admin::vbk_emp_ing01.index', ['page' => $page]),
        'page'             => $page,
        'registro_fiscal'  => $request->old('registro_fiscal'),
        'nombre'           => $request->old('nombre'),
        'razon_social'     => $request->old('razon_social'),
        'giro'             => $request->old('giro'),
        'telefono_central' => $request->old('telefono_central'),
        'web'              => $request->old('web'),
        'infpaises_id'     => $request->old('infpaises_id')
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

No entendí muy bien tu pregunta pero para asignar el valor `old` en una etiqueta `select` basta con comparar el valor de la opción con el valor `old`.

```
<select name="pais" id="pais">
   <option value="">Seleccionar valor</select>
   <option value="1" {{ old('pais') == 1 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Opción 1</option>
   <option value="2" {{ old('pais') == 2 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Opción 2</option>
</select>
```