# Cargar datos de BD a un campo select en editar Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas estoy intentando hacer la parte de actualizar de un formulario pero tengo una duda, no se como pasar el parametro old a un campo de tipo select. Estoy utilizando larave con vistas blade.

para graficar lo que tengo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los campos del Formulario

```
      <div class="col-4" id="id_especiec">
    <label for="id_especie" class="requerido">Especie</label>
    <select  class="form-control" id="id_especie" name="id_especie"  value=""  required >
      <option value="">Seleccione Especie</option>
      @foreach ($especies as $especie)
      <option value="{{$especie['id_especie']}}">{{$especie->especie['nombre_especie']}}</option>
      @endforeach  
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label for="id_especie_raza" class="requerido">Raza</label>
    <select  class="form-control" id="id_especie_raza" name="id_especie_raza"  value=""  required ></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  <div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <label for="fecha_nacimiento" class="requerido">Fecha Nacimiento    </label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha_nacimiento" placeholder="Fecha Nacimiento" value="{{old('fecha_nacimiento',$data->fecha_nacimiento  ?? '')}}" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label for="sexo" class="requerido">Sexo</label>
    <select  class="form-control" id="sexo" name="sexo"  required >
      <option value="">Seleccione una Opción</option>
        <option value="M">Macho</option>
        <option value="H">Hembra</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" >
    <label for="color" class="requerido">Color</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="color" placeholder="Color" value="{{old('color',$data->color  ?? '')}}" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

he intentado hacer esto en option pero me sigue salieron el campo "selecione Sexo"

```
       <select  class="form-control" id="sexo" name="sexo"  required >
      <option value="">Seleccione una Opción</option>
        <option value="M" {{ (old($data->sexo) === 'M' ? "selected":"") }}>Macho</option>
        <option value="H">Hembra</option>
      </select>
```

lo que necesito es que al dar click en editar, se carguen los datos que estan almacenados en la base de datos y no se como hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo usar el old de un select Laravel?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/217838/c%c3%b3mo-usar-el-old-de-un-select-laravel)

Comment: @BetaM eso mismo estoy intentanto si ves la ultima imagen pero al dar click en editar me sigue saliendo como primera opcion **Seleccione una Opción** y lo que necesito es que al dar clic en editar y cargue la pagina salga la opcion  Macho para el ejemplo que puse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno encontré lo que necesitaba de la ayuda de un experto.

Para mostrar los datos que tiene un registro de la base de datos en los selects no se debe usar old se debe hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
        <select  class="form-control" id="castrado" name="castrado"   required >
      <option value="">Seleccione una Opción</option>
        <option value="1" @if($data->castrado == 1) selected  @endif >Si</option>
        <option value="0" @if($data->castrado == 0) selected  @endif>No</option>
      </select>
```